# remove excessive div from html python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have exmaple of HTML:

```
<br><div><h3>Rozszerzony opis</h3><br><div><div><div><div><img alt="" src="https://emos.eu/FOTO-PC/RGB72_400x400/1525733234_E17-ZQ5140W.JPG"/></div><br></div><div><br><div><h3>Ściemnialna żarówka LED EMOS</h3><br><p>Nasza <strong>ściemnialna żarówka LED EMOS </strong>gwarantuje stworzenie przyjemnej atmosfery w zaciszu Twojego domu.  Dzięki ściemniaczowi żarówka będzie zawsze świecić zgodnie z Twoimi życzeniami. Chcesz cieszyć się filmem z rodziną <strong>przy przyciemnionym świetle</strong> lub potrzebujesz <strong>pełnej mocy </strong>do pracy? To zależy od ciebie. <strong>Jesteś teraz mistrzem oświetlenia domowego. </strong></p></div></div></div></div><br><div> </div><br><div><div><div><div><img alt="" src="https://emos.eu/FOTO-PC/RGB72_400x400/1525733234_P40-ZQ5140W.JPG"/></div><br></div><div><br><div><h3>To od ciebie zależy, jakiej chcesz mocy.</h3><br><p>Na pierwszy rzut oka nie widać różnicy w porównaniu z tradycyjną żarówką LED, a jednak <strong>potrafi ona o wiele więcej</strong>. Dzięki 3-stopniowemu ściemnianiu w <strong>ciepłych kolorach </strong>za<strong> </strong>każdym razem zapewni Ci idealną ilość światła. W przeciwieństwie do innych żarówek, <strong>nie trzeba do niej kupować ściemniacza. Intensywność światła </strong>można łatwo regulować za pomocą klasycznego przełącznika - poprzez wielokrotne włączanie i wyłączanie żarówki.</p></div></div></div></div><br><div> </div><br><div><div><div><div><br><h3>Właściwe światło dla Twojego domu</h3><br><div><div><p>Dzięki doskonałej <strong>żywotności wynoszącej około 30 000 godzin, </strong>żarówka ta jest doskonałym rozwiązaniem dla wymagających użytkowników. Zapewnia przyciemnione oświetlenie o strumieniu świetlnym <strong>806 lm. </strong>Dzięki temu jest przeznaczona do stworzenia odpowiedniego nastroju w salonie lub sypialni. Posiada gwint <strong>E27</strong>, dzięki któremu można ją wkręcić do większości opraw oświetleniowych w domu. W połączeniu z typowym kształtem żarówki (A60) wypełnia każde pomieszczenie przyjemnym, ciepłym światłem pod kątem <strong>250°.</strong></p></div></div><br></div></div></div></div><br><div> </div><br><div><div><div><div><img alt="" src="https://emos.eu/FOTO-PC/RGB72_850x850/1525733234_E88-ZQ5140W.JPG"/></div></div></div><br></div><div> </div><br></div>
```

As you see, there is really much `<div>...</div>` which is unnecessary.
How to get rid of this?

Comment: Please as a constructive question, what is unnecessary?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis The div tags in the Q were not backtick-escaped.

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis
<div><div><div><div>....</div></div></div></div><div> </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you could go with `unwrap()`, to get a more specific solution, it needs improvment of your question:

```
for d in soup.find_all('div'):
    d.unwrap()
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<br><div><h3>Rozszerzony opis</h3><br><div><div><div><div><img alt="" src="https://emos.eu/FOTO-PC/RGB72_400x400/1525733234_E17-ZQ5140W.JPG"/></div><br></div><div><br><div><h3>Ściemnialna żarówka LED EMOS</h3><br><p>Nasza <strong>ściemnialna żarówka LED EMOS </strong>gwarantuje stworzenie przyjemnej atmosfery w zaciszu Twojego domu.  Dzięki ściemniaczowi żarówka będzie zawsze świecić zgodnie z Twoimi życzeniami. Chcesz cieszyć się filmem z rodziną <strong>przy przyciemnionym świetle</strong> lub potrzebujesz <strong>pełnej mocy </strong>do pracy? To zależy od ciebie. <strong>Jesteś teraz mistrzem oświetlenia domowego. </strong></p></div></div></div></div><br><div> </div><br><div><div><div><div><img alt="" src="https://emos.eu/FOTO-PC/RGB72_400x400/1525733234_P40-ZQ5140W.JPG"/></div><br></div><div><br><div><h3>To od ciebie zależy, jakiej chcesz mocy.</h3><br><p>Na pierwszy rzut oka nie widać różnicy w porównaniu z tradycyjną żarówką LED, a jednak <strong>potrafi ona o wiele więcej</strong>. Dzięki 3-stopniowemu ściemnianiu w <strong>ciepłych kolorach </strong>za<strong> </strong>każdym razem zapewni Ci idealną ilość światła. W przeciwieństwie do innych żarówek, <strong>nie trzeba do niej kupować ściemniacza. Intensywność światła </strong>można łatwo regulować za pomocą klasycznego przełącznika - poprzez wielokrotne włączanie i wyłączanie żarówki.</p></div></div></div></div><br><div> </div><br><div><div><div><div><br><h3>Właściwe światło dla Twojego domu</h3><br><div><div><p>Dzięki doskonałej <strong>żywotności wynoszącej około 30 000 godzin, </strong>żarówka ta jest doskonałym rozwiązaniem dla wymagających użytkowników. Zapewnia przyciemnione oświetlenie o strumieniu świetlnym <strong>806 lm. </strong>Dzięki temu jest przeznaczona do stworzenia odpowiedniego nastroju w salonie lub sypialni. Posiada gwint <strong>E27</strong>, dzięki któremu można ją wkręcić do większości opraw oświetleniowych w domu. W połączeniu z typowym kształtem żarówki (A60) wypełnia każde pomieszczenie przyjemnym, ciepłym światłem pod kątem <strong>250°.</strong></p></div></div><br></div></div></div></div><br><div> </div><br><div><div><div><div><img alt="" src="https://emos.eu/FOTO-PC/RGB72_850x850/1525733234_E88-ZQ5140W.JPG"/></div></div></div><br></div><div> </div><br></div> 
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for d in soup.find_all('div'):
    d.unwrap()
soup
```